# Jasypt Android forgot password

Tags: php, android, passwords, jasypt

I'm stuck with a problem and I need your help with it.
In my Android app I encrypt passwords with Jasypt. This one 
way encryption works fine. I store my passwords on an external mysql database where
I check the encrypted passwords when the app does syncing and stuff. 
Now I want to create a script in php where users can generate a tempor new password when they've forgotten their old password. This tempor password will be send to their email address. The problem is that I don't know how I can encrypt the tempor password just like how Jasypt encrypts their passwords. Am I missing something or is there a smarter, safer and easier way? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Phpsypt encryption for jasypt (1.9)

https://github.com/kevwis/Phpsypt